# Asp.net UserManager and IUserStore - username and password both required to retrieve user

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I found myself in a requirement for providing username and password together to retrieve a user account from my custom IUserStore through UserManager.  Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any support for this.  The only method I see that takes in username/password in UserManager is `Task<TUser> FindAsync(string userName, string password)` which internally calls `Task<TUser> this.Store.FindByNameAsync(userName)` and then validates the password by calling `this.VerifyPassword(passwordStore, tUser, password))` (thanks ILSpy).

I don't have the option of getting user password based on username alone.  Validation can only succeed if I provide username and password in the same call.  I ended up sub-classing UserManager and adding my own method `TUser FindUserAndPassword(string userName, string password)` which makes a single call to my custom store api providing both username and password (I could also override `FindUser(string UserName, string password)`instead of adding a new method).

Even though this works I'm really surprised that the new Identity framework doesn't support this requirement out of the box.  Maybe I'm not seeing something.  Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core framework does not require passwords to find users, the expectation is that you should be able to lookup a user via its keys (ID/UserName).  But if this is a requirement for your app, what you are currently doing (extending UserManager and adding your own APIs) is the intended way for you to add your own functionality.